# Regex to for .split() to separate string on spaces except for quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to use a Regex to split a string into spaces and quotes? I can only use `.split()` instead of `.match()` for performance reasons.

Example:

```
'This is an "example for" stack overflow.'
```

Output:

```
["This", "is", "an", "example for", "stack", "overflow"]
```

Comment: *"I can only use .split() instead of .match() for performance reasons."* Huh? Can you expand on that a bit please? Also, what has your research into this turned up? What about escaped quotes? What sorts of things have you tried?

Comment: This sounds rather contradictory. If you are fine with using a Regex then how is that any better than using `str.match(re)`? *Or* if you can't use `str.match(re)`, then a Regex seems out of the question. And `.split()` does not have Regex support.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question is Yes, you can use a regex in String.prototype.split().
This is the code you want based on your example:

```
'This is an "example for" stack overflow.'.split(/\"\s|\s\"|\s|\"/g);
```

Comment: This gives wrong output result as it even splits by space within double quotes. `[ "This", "is", "an", "example", "for", "stack", "overflow."]`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting the string, it will be easier for you to capture them in tokens either purely a word or capture a word having space within but enclosed within double quotes with using this regex,

```
"([\w ]*?)"|\w+
```

Sample Javascript code for same is following,

```js
var s = 'This is an "example for" stack overflow.';
var re = /"([\w ]*?)"|\w+/g;
var arr = [];
do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        if (m[1]) {
            arr.push(m[1]);
        } else if (m[0]) {
            arr.push(m[0]);
        }
        
    }
} while (m);

console.log(arr);
```